# Program is not working. Compiles and runs ok, but if I enter a number, it just crashes

Tags: c

I have isolated the section of the code which is giving me the issue:

```
int i;

printf("Hit [1] to begin");
scanf("%d", i);

if (i == 1)
    printf("The program will now execute");
else
    printf("Error.")
```

Whenever I try to compile the program, I get no warnings or errors, but when I run it within CMD and I type 1 to run my program, a window pops up saying that the program stopped working and it automatically quit the task.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have two open brackets and no close brackets?

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to `scanf` syntax  before that try to clear all the compiler warnings. If you clear you may not come into this kind of situation.

Error in`scanf("%d", i);`

solution `scanf("%d", &i);` you need to provide address for the variable `i` using `&`.

This is the reason it is crashing because address issue.

Comment: I quick note that compiler warnings would have caught this immediately.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me!

Comment: @user3477984 community is there to help you anytime.